# Ordenar numeros pares y mayores al principio y luego los impares ordenadors

Tags: c++

Quiero hacer un programa que con un vector me coloque al principio los pares(y que estén ordenados de mayor a menor) y luego los impares(y estén ordenados de mayor a menor también).
El orden correcto de mi ejemplo sería: 50,10,8,2,45,21,13. Os dejo aquí el código que llevo hecho:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int v[7]={10,50,21,13,45,2,8};
    int aux;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(v[i]%2!=0){
            for(int j=i;j<7;j++){
                if(v[j]%2==0){
                    aux=v[j];
                    v[j]=v[i];
                    v[i]=aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

**Primero colocar al principio del arreglo los pares (desde `0` hasta `m`), y después los impares (desde `m + 1` hasta el final).**

```cpp
std::array<int, 7> array = {10,50,21,13,45,2,8};

// colocar al inicio del array los pares
size_t swap_idx = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
    if (array.at(i) % 2 == 0) {
        // intercambia el número que NO es par (swap_idx), por el que sí es par (i)
        // para dejar todos los pares juntos
        std::swap(array.at(i), array.at(swap_idx));
        ++swap_idx;
    }
}
```

En ese código podría decirse que sólo se están ordenando los números pares, pero dado que solamente hay pares e impares, cuando se separan los pares, lógicamente se separan también los impares, y la variable `swap_idx` al final del ciclo tiene la posición del primer número impar en el arreglo. Todos los impares atrás de esa posición deberían de ser pares.

Esto toma tiempo `O(n)`

**Después ordenas los pares y después los impares.**

```cpp
// ordenar pares
std::sort(array.begin(), array.begin() + swap_idx, std::greater<int>());

// ordenar impares
std::sort(array.begin() + swap_idx, array.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

Nótese que el límite superior para ordenar los pares es igual al límite inferior para los impares `array.begin() + swap_idx`, esto es porque el límite superior para [`std::sort`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) es **exclusivo**, mientras que el inferior es **inclusivo**.

Utilizamos `std::greater<int>()` para ordenar de mayor a menor.

Esto toma tiempo `O(nlog(n))` (es como si ordenaramos el arreglo completo, sólo que lo hacemos en dos pasos)

Al final el algoritmo tiene complejidad **`O(nlog(n))`**

Te dejo el código completo

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 7> array = {10,50,21,13,45,2,8};

    // colocar al inicio del array los pares
    size_t last_swapped_idx = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
        if (array.at(i) % 2 == 0) {
            std::swap(array.at(i), array.at(last_swapped_idx));
            ++last_swapped_idx;
        }
    }

    // ordenar pares
    std::sort(array.begin(), array.begin() + last_swapped_idx);

    // ordenar impares
    std::sort(array.begin() + last_swapped_idx, array.end());

    for (int el : array)
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
}
```

Igual te dejo la versión con punteros de C, que es como estás manejando tu código, aunque si es C++, lo ideal sería utilizar cosas de C++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main() {
    int array[7] = {10,50,21,13,45,2,8};
    size_t len = 7;

    // colocar al inicio del array los pares
    size_t swap_idx = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            std::swap(array[i], array[swap_idx]);
            ++swap_idx;
        }
    }

    // ordenar pares
    std::sort(array, array + swap_idx, std::greater<int>());

    // ordenar impares
    std::sort(array + swap_idx, array + len, std::greater<int>());

    for (int el : array)
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
}
```